# Check if nullable reference types are enabled for the project

Tags: roslyn

Can I see if the nullable reference types are enabled, from the Roslyn `Compilation` object?
The configuration is inside `.csproj`, but I would prefer if it setting can be retrieved from the Compilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the project-level setting from [CompilationOptions.NullableContextOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.csharpcompilationoptions.nullablecontextoptions?view=roslyn-dotnet-4.1.0). Depending on what you are doing, [SemanticModel.GetNullableContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.semanticmodel.getnullablecontext?view=roslyn-dotnet-4.1.0) may be a better choice though if you need to know the state at a specific point in a file, since that'll also consider #nullable directives.

Comment: Thanks. The property's name got me confused when I first saw it.